# How to send values into command prompt from groovy?

Tags: groovy

I tried to pass an command or value at runtime into command prompt from groovy script.
could anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your command in an Array: then use `execute ()` to run as in command prompt like shown below.

```
def command = ['ls']
command.execute()
```

I feel like you are looking for a method like this: Use this method.

```
void executejar (String jarname)
{
   def command = ['java','-jar', jarname ]
   println command.execute().text
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually i am trying to execute a jar file using command prompt. And need to pass the values into command prompt. How to access command prompt directly from groovy.

Comment: @vadivelu If you just want to "execte" a jar file, then `java -jar thefile.jar` is the way to go.  could you please be more specific about your problem (via adding more infos to your question)

Comment: @vadivelu Just check with my answer.

Comment: I have tried the below code. But i am not able to see any output here in soap UI. def command = "java -jar E2EEHelper_V7.jar"
def process = command.execute()
process.waitFor()
 
def output = process.in.text
log.info output

Comment: But when i execute the same jar file in cmd prompt ( java -jar xxx.jar) i could see the some output there. Where i have to give the further values as input to proceed further. Very similar way i m trying here in soap UI instead of using cmd prompt. Hope you got my point.

Comment: @vadivelu To get output Use `command.execute().text` and to get error details use `command.execute().err.text`. Check these outputs.

Comment: i am getting the error of unable to access the jar file. Note: i have kept the jar file in the bin>ext folder. I want to add one more point here. Normally I need two certificate file two execute the jar file. I kept everything under ext folder. Still getting the same error in soap UI. Whereas im able to run via cmd prompt.

Comment: @Uchiha_Itachi Thanks it's working fine now. My jar has the class which has multiple switch cases. Based on the choice i chose it would produce the output. How to give the continuous input to get the proper output.

Comment: @vadivelu Fine.. Enjoy coding...:)